# Build error with next-intel and not-found.tsx with NX

Tags: reactjs, next.js, production-environment, next-intl

I have this mono-repo setup, using NX. one of my nextjs application inside does not build and keeps complaining about _not-found.tsx file and the error is coming from the `next-intl` as it seems. my app is compiling and run in dev env, it keeps failing on production build though.

here's the error I'm getting.

```
nx run <project-name>:build:production

- info Loaded env from C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\apps\iprox.open.portal\.env.production.local
- info Creating an optimized production build...
- info Using tsconfig file: ./tsconfig.prod.json
- info Compiled successfully
- info Skipping linting
- info Checking validity of types...
- info Collecting page data...
- info Generating static pages (0/3)
Error: Usage of next-intl APIs in Server Components is currently only available for dynamic rendering (i.e. no `generateStaticParams`).
Support for static rendering is under consideration, please refer to the roadmap: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components#roadmap
    at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:29896:19
    at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:32365:23
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at async C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:860:60 {
  [cause]: DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers
      at staticGenerationBailout (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:30425:21)
      at headers (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:30245:62)
      at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:29888:51
      at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:32365:23
      at useLocale (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:29914:12)       
      at RootLayout (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\480.js:2822:48)       
      at preloadComponent (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\preload-component.js:23:22)
      at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:626:101
      at async createComponentTree (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:626:29)
      at async C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:860:60 {
    digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
  }
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Usage of next-intl APIs in Server Components is currently only available for dynamic rendering (i.e. no `generateStaticParams`).       
Support for static rendering is under consideration, please refer to the roadmap: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components#roadmap
    at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:29896:19
    at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:32365:23
    at useLocale (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\249.js:29914:12)
    at RootLayout (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\dist\apps\iprox.open.portal\.next\server\chunks\480.js:2822:48)
    at preloadComponent (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\preload-component.js:23:22)
    at C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:626:101
    at async createComponentTree (C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:626:29)
    at async C:\Users\saniraa\Documents\iprox.open\applications\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\app-render.js:860:60
- info Generating static pages (3/3)
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /_not-found
Error occurred while trying to run the build command
1
```

here's the folder structure I'm having inside my nextjs app.

[image]

I'm using `next-intl v-3.0.0-beta.5`
`nextjs v-13.4.12`
`react v-18.2.0`

please not that if I make `not-found.tsx` into `_not-found.tsx` then the build is running but the expected behavior (fallback to not-found page) with next not happening. any insight would be really nice here and, one strange thing I noticed also with current implementation though, if the app encounters an unknown route, it will fallback to `not-found` page correctly, but it seems keeps trying to fetch the data which is giving me `404` in the network tab the fetch call is also keeps running. (strange..!).